# What actually is dotnet.exe and what is its purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I noticed when I run .NET Core app e.g

```
dotnet new console
dotnet run
```

then there's process called `dotnet.exe`

but what's actually the purpose of it? does it have something with changing code at fly / JIT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a command line tool for telling .NET Core what it should do, e.g. "build my solution" or "build & run my solution" or "create a solution for me" or "add a project to my solution" + many other commands.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet

You can even [extend it with your own subcommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create).